# How to populate currency symbols in html 5 input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, utf-8

I have the following html Input element:

```
<input size=6 type="text" id="prd_price" title="prd_price" name="prd_price" >
```

I want Currency Symbol  **ман** for "Azerbaijani manat
"  to be saved in the database. I would like to populate this as the symbol inside HTML Input element and perhaps concatenate with the price of a product. But when I populate the Input Element dynamically with the UTF-8 Code, it remains in the code form and does not become the Currency Symbol it is suppose to become.

Anyone knows what am I missing here...

Comment: works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/m1hu1hv9/

Comment: Why exactly do you have HTML entities in the first place? And, in any case, HTML entities work fine in plain HTML. Are you using a scripting language you haven't mentioned?

Comment: Yes I used JQuery Ajax functions to get the UTF-8 characters from database, concatenate and populate the input element with the price of the product in that input element.

Comment: for js https://jsfiddle.net/m1hu1hv9/1/, your next best friend : http://www.fileformat.info/index.htm

Comment: I use JQuery .val() function to populate the input element, but after population the currency code is shown as it is and not as a symbol, but the price, whom with I have concatenated the currency code with, shows as the price.

Comment: First of all, HTML entities are compatible with 7-bit US-ASCII so forget your concerns about UTF-8. Secondly, you're most likely handling HTML as plain text in your code. But since you haven't shared any code it's impossible to say what's wrong.

Comment: @UmarAbbasKhan, don't use HTML entities out of HTML. `.val` is setting the DOM property named `value`, so you need the source code variation of your characters (respectively `\u043C`, `\u0430` and `\u043D`).
Ps: according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azerbaijani_manat) and [fileformat](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20bc/index.htm), the correct unicode character for Manat is `U+20BC` (or `&#8380;` in HTML entities) but on my system, it looks more like a stroked P... ₼

Comment: @Kaiido I used the Javascript Unicode Version aswell, but none of the codes I got from "https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/" are working in the input element, all are showing the code itself and not the symbol, i need.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all I got the UTF-8 Code for Azerbaijani manat ман which is able to be run in javascript from "https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/". In this case it came up to be `\u043C\u0430\u043D`. Then I ran it up with the following code to get it display inside the input element using javascript:

```js
var x = "\u043C\u0430\u043D";
var r = /\\u([\d\w]{4})/gi;
x = x.replace(r, function (match, grp) {
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(grp, 16)); } );
x = unescape(x);
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 2):

The UTF-8 encoding can represent the complete Unicode catalogue (in fact, the letter *U* in the acronym comes from *Unicode*) so you don't need HTML entities in the first place. Such entities are only necessary if have characters that your current encoding cannot handle, which isn't the case here.

If you absolutely need to use those HTML entities (e.g., you consume a third-party data feed you cannot tweak) you need to realise that they only make sense in HTML context. A fairly common error in jQuery is to use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2) where you should really be using [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2).

In this precise situation you have an `<input>` element so you cannot use either. Your only choice is [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2). However, since an `<input>` cannot contain HTML at all everything you feed `.val()` with will be eventually handled as plain text.

A little trick you can use is to create a detached node so you can use `.html()` to populate it with HTML and `.text()` to extract the plain text representation:

```
var $input = $("#prd_price");
// Original string "&#1084 ;&#1072 ;&#1085 ;" fixed:
var symbols = "&#1084;&#1072;&#1085;"
var plainText = $("<span></span>").html(symbols).text()
$input.val(plainText);
```

... will render as:

```
ман
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/lavuyusini/1/edit?js,output)